# How do I change group ownership on folders created by a specific user?

Tags: permissions, chown

I have `user` who has created a folder and so the permissions are `user:user`. I have now added `user` to `group` so my question is how can I update all folders created by `user`, as if I'd done `chown user:group`, but not *all* folders, because some have different owners. In effect - refresh folders to update the new group rights? Filezilla lists them still with the old `user:group` permissions.

Comment: `chown :group folder1 folder2 folder3`? What's wrong with that?

Comment: Me being silly. I didn't know you could just use :group and didn't have to do user:group. I will leave this in case anyone else comes across it.

Comment: Why use chown for just changing the group if there is an explicit command for that called "chgrp"?

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` to do this:

```
find -type d -user $USER -exec chown :groupname {} +
```

it will finds all directories which belongs to the user `$USER` and changes the group of them to `groupname`.

- Note: `$USER` is the current user you can change it with your desired one.

Comment: And I'd use the test for group ownership instead of user ownership (for cases like `user:group2`) (Also, `-exec ... {} +`)

Comment: @muru I didn't get your point :/ (find updated)

Comment: Right now files are owned by `user:user`, but some, according to OP, have different owners (say `user2:user` or `user:group2`). In that case, it'd make sense to only change `:user` to `:group`.

Comment: @muru  got it ;)